# How to embed dash app in existing platform with security?

Tags: authentication, flask, plotly-dash

We run some dash apps in dockers, and we want to embed them into our platform (it's built with React for UI and Flask for API server). Our platform use Flask JWT for authentication. What's the best way to secure the embedded dash apps?
We are thinking embed the dash apps by using iframe. We want user to login to our platform to use the dash app. When user uses the dash app via our platform, user will not be asked for username and password again. But if user copies the dash app url to another browser, user will be ask for login(to prevent the url to be shared). How to do it?

thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.